# IComparable not sorting objects correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, object

I have a list of objects that store search results for a feed search I have made.  While adding to the list I give the object a score on how relevant the result is so that I can push these results to the top.

My object implements the `IComparable` interface and has a compareto function and all compiles correctly but when I sort the list (list.sort()) this doesn't seem to have any effect on the results (the higher scored items are not at the top of the bottom)

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

```
Public Class SearchFeedItem
    Implements IComparable

    Private _score As Integer = 0

    Public Property Score() As Integer
        Get
            Return _score
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _score = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal obj As Object) As Integer Implements System.IComparable.CompareTo
        Dim OtherItem As SearchFeedItem = CType(obj, SearchFeedItem)

        If Me.Score < OtherItem.Score Then
            Return 1
        End If

        If Me.Score > OtherItem.Score Then
            Return -1
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I have implemented as above but still not sorting correctly, new code:     Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As SearchFeedItem) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of SearchFeedItem).CompareTo
        If Me.Score < other.Score Then
            Return 1
        End If

        If Me.Score > other.Score Then
            Return -1
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the higher scored items at the bottom, it should be

```
 Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo

    If obj Is Nothing Then Return 1
    If Me.Score > DirectCast(obj, SortableObject).Score Then Return 1
    If Me.Score < DirectCast(obj, SortableObject).Score Then Return -1

    Return 0

    End Function
```

Here's a quick example of an object implementing `IComparable` which sorts from low to high.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim sortableObjects = New List(Of SortableObject) From
                               {New SortableObject With {.Score = 12},
                               New SortableObject With {.Score = 5},
                               New SortableObject With {.Score = 120},
                               New SortableObject With {.Score = 99}}

        sortableObjects.Sort() // 5, 9, 99, 120
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class SortableObject : Implements IComparable
    Public Property Score As Integer

    Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo

    If obj Is Nothing Then Return 1
    If Me.Score > DirectCast(obj, SortableObject).Score Then Return 1
    If Me.Score < DirectCast(obj, SortableObject).Score Then Return -1

    Return 0
    // Edit: Or as Konrad mentioned,  Return (Me.Score.CompareTo(DirectCast(obj, SortableObject).Score)). This sorts the items in ascending order.

    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Hans said in the comment (you need to implement the generic interface!), there are two things about the code which make me cringe:

1. Use `DirectCast` instead of `CType`. The latter is a general-purpose cast that doesn’t show very well what’s actually done here. `DirectCast` only allows certain casts to happen, notably no conversions. It’s appropriate here since you don’t convert.
2. The whole `CompareTo` method can be shortened to a single line:

   ```
   Return Score.CompareTo(OtherItem.Score)
   ```